# Having trouble with Moralis cloud function

Tags: parse-platform, ethereum, web3js, moralis

Function bellow returns nothing when should return a json string also not showing input in logs

```
Moralis.Cloud.define("getMeta", async (request,uri) => {
  const logger = Moralis.Cloud.getLogger();
let results; 
results = await Moralis.Cloud.httpRequest({
  url: 'https://defi-city.com/api/city/463',
    followRedirects: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
  }
}).then(function(httpResponse) {
    results=httpResponse.text;
    logger.info("over here"+results);
    logger.info(httpResponse.text);
}, function(httpResponse) {
  logger.info('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
});
  logger.info("end"+results);
  return await results;
});
let mData = await Moralis.Cloud.run("getMeta",uri);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `return` solved the problem

```
Moralis.Cloud.define("getMeta", async (request, uri) => {
      const logger = Moralis.Cloud.getLogger();
      let results;
      results = await Moralis.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: "https://defi-city.com/api/city/463",
        followRedirects: true,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        },
      }).then(
        function (httpResponse) {
          results = httpResponse.text;
          logger.info("over here" + results);
          logger.info(httpResponse.text);
          return results; //There
        }
      );
      logger.info("end" + results);
      return results;
    });
```